# Can someone find a post of mine about ebook apps?

Tags: support

I remember I asked in a post or maybe a comment about how to convert an app which is actually an ebook to a document format such as pdf. But I can't find it no matter how. How can I find it, or can someone find it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the site search in the top-right corner? If you add `user:me` to the input, it'll limit the search to your own posts. NB don't try it here because this search box only searches the meta site.

Comment: The question seems to be deleted, either by mods, or by automatic clean-up script. (I saw the question at that time, but I don't have enough rep to see deleted posts)

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't have enough rep to see posts deleted too long ago either. I am not sure if the post has been deleted either.

Comment: @Dan will your way also search in my comments?

Comment: @Tim Comments aren't indexed for search. That's one reason (amongst others) you shouldn't use them for information that needs to stick around.

Comment: Maybe you can post your question again.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the link](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/138223/1465).  As for why it was removed:

> deleted by Community♦ Apr 2 at 0:33 (RemoveDeadQuestions)
>
> This question was automatically deleted. [Please see the help center for more information.](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/roomba)

Comment: thanks. what is the definition of a dead question?

Comment: @Tim Follow that Help Center link.